# Why is REGEXP_MATCH not working like expected in Google Data Studio?

Tags: postgresql, looker-studio

I try to generate better reports in Google Data Studio. So I started using custom fields with regular expressions, which do not work like expected.

Given for example a custom field `city` with the value "I love Berlin" in it i created this statement:

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(city,".*Berlin.*") THEN "Berlin"         
  ELSE "Other"
END
```

My expected result would be a match with a returned "Berlin", but I get "Other" instead.

I tried a few different things without positive results.

Answer (score 2):

The [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statement provided in the question works as expected (***edit***: for future reference, this was a *bug*, that was specific to the PostgreSQL connector, and that since been resolved; see note below).

You could have a look at adding a `(`capturing group`)` as well as adding a case insensitive flag `(?i)` to see if that resolves the issue:

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(city, ".*(?i)(Berlin).*") THEN "Berlin"
  ELSE "Other"
END
```

**Note**: The [25 Mar 2021 update](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10331528?hl=en#mar-25-2021) explicitly states that the issue was resolved for the *PostgreSQL connector*:

> **Improved text functions in PostgreSQL**
> We've fixed a bug that prevented the [`CONTAINS_TEXT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9366283), [`STARTS_WITH`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9366525), [`ENDS_WITH`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9366729), and [`REGEXP_MATCH`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7064476) [functions](https://support.google.com/datastudio/table/6379764) from working correctly with the [PostgreSQL connector](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7288010).

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/a02ab976-4ed2-48db-b76f-468bb11fa263) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q1sOu1ODWX9Eeprr5BSado9DOg7vvilwKrjXUYSvFwM/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Regexp functions can't be used with the Postgres live connector (maybe MySQL as well). I solved my problem using data extraction for the fields I needed to do regex stuff on and included the created diagrams to my report which is connected to the live connector as well.